# To reset game, will I need to add objects dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Good evening/ morning.

I am creating a game in As3 where the enemies are added not added dynamically.

```
if(hero attacks enemy)
{ then parent.removeChild(enemy) }
```

When the hero attacks the enemy the enemy removes it self from the display list I presume.

but when you reset the level, i.e go back to the start menu and go back to the level you will see the enemies are not in the level, since they've been removed.

My question is, is there a way I can reset the display object in that frame, in As2 I refreshed the flash movie. But that's not good in terms of coding as it shows you are not developing or learning.

IF there is no way, will you suggest adding the objects that will be removed, dynamically?

another question is that my level is in a container.

```
//on the stage, there is a movieclip called container. 
//In this container mc(movie clip) it contains the whole level, including platforms,
  //enemies and props
```

IF I remove a prop from that container, in order to reset the game will I do this

```
container.addChild(prop)
//the question is that how do I set it's x and y position?
```

Thank you, I will appreciate every ones feedback and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you remove them dynamically, you need to add them dynamically again in order to reset them. You either predefine their positions and set them again, or you can just hide those enemies and make them visible once again the game resets. Depends on your code and structure.

Comment: if I hide the enemies, visible = false. The enemy still interacts with my player, unless I remove it from the array. But I can't remove it from the array because I can't access for for loop from my enemy class.

Comment: What do you mean by 'interact'? You can disable them (either with mouseEnabled, or with any kind of variables inside them).

Comment: like hit Test with the enemy will be true, because it's on the stage but invisible. But what I will do, is move the enemy off screen and reset their position and not make it visible. When the enemy dies, it goes to a blank key frame.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, instead of removing them from the display list, your best bet is to hide then and put them and reset their position back to their original point.

A good practice to get into is to avoid the chance of runaway instantiation if at all possible; this means, if you're going to instantiate and remove enemies every time they're spawned and killed, the garbage collector has to work very hard to keep up. A better approach would be to have a pool of enemies that is as large enough to support as many enemies as you would ever need at one time.